# How to Manually select a Environment in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have requirement that jenkins pipeline stage has to ask which environment has to select(manual) for the continuous delivery and then progress with other steps

Answer (score 0):

The [input step of a pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) is meant for asking manual input. The submitter can provide values for parameters, which can then be reused in the rest of the stage.